# Tomcat subdomain SSL

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, tomcat, https, subdomain

I am using ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse directives for redirecting all requests from Tomcat's application (from port 8080) to subdomain (port 80). In addition I have default php website on port 80. So the config looks like:

```
<VirtualHost xx.xx.xx.xx:80 >
    ServerName domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost xx.xx.xx.xx:80 >
    ServerName sub.domain.com
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    <Proxy *>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

Now I have to add a SSL support so I added the following lines into config:

```
NameVirtualHost *:443
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /usr/local/ssl/crt/public.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/local/ssl/private/private.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /usr/local/ssl/crt/intermediate.crt
    ServerName domain.com:443
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site
</VirtualHost>
```

But the problem that https works fine only on root site, but when I am trying to get subdomains via https it redirects me to non-existing page... How can I configure the apache in order to implement this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't added an SSL (port 443) virtualHost for sub.domain.com e.g.

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
ServerName sub.domain.com

SSLEngine On
SSLCertificateFile /usr/local/ssl/crt/public.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/local/ssl/private/private.key
SSLCACertificateFile /usr/local/ssl/crt/intermediate.crt

ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
<Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
</Proxy>

# Needed if you want to go to preserve the SSL connection all the way to tomcat,
# but not worth it as both daemons are on the same physical box.
#SSLProxyEngine On  

ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```